# Reverse marginpar keeping marginparsep and marginparwidth with geometry

Tags: margins, marginpar, marginnote, leftmargin

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{
    includeall,
    outer=1cm, 
    inner=2cm, 
    top=1cm, 
    bottom=1cm,
    footskip=1cm,
    headsep=0.25cm,
    headheight=0.5cm,
    marginparsep=0.5cm,
    marginparwidth=1.5cm
}
%\reversemarginpar
\usepackage{sidenotes}    
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \sidenote{hello world}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

This produces as output the image on the left, while what I need is something as sketched in the middle. Simply uncommenting `\reversemarginpar`yields the result on the right, which is wrong as well. Any simple solution? What I need to is basically mirror pages vertically. This would be equivalent to make all pages verso if `report` was `doublesided` (solutions changing the class to `book` if needed are welcome as well).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Does that mean you want every page to be an even page?

Comment: Sort of. The ideal solution would be like passing the asymmetric option to geometry, but all pages would look like even, instead of odd (whilst retaining their "oddness/evenness")